# Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of resource 'Count' in namespace 'AnonymousId'

Tags: visual-studio, download, ide, vscode-extensions

unable to download any vs code extension

want to download vs code extension
Request was blocked due to exceeding usage of resource 'Count' in namespace 'AnonymousId'. For more information on why your request was blocked, see the topic "Rate limits" on the Microsoft Web site